# Partial event syncing when importing calendar into Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, apple-ical

I'm trying to import my university's calendar into Google Calendar. However, both methods I use give me the same result.

1. When I directly choose to save the ".ics" file to my desktop and then import to Google Calendar, it only inserts the five most recent upcoming events.
2. The second method also yields the same result. I subscribed to the "iCal feed" that opens in Outlook 2013. Then I exported the calendar from Outlook to the desktop. After that, I added that ".ics" file to Google Calendar.

Does it mean that the ".ics" file will be updated automatically with newer events as time passes? That's because the calendar on the university's website has many more than just five events. Or am I doing something wrong? I think it has something to do with the calendar itself, because even when I did option #2, the calendar on Outlook only had the five most recent upcoming events.